# Win Phone RT LimeLight SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Hello Community can anyone help me port this [Authentication utility](http://support.video.limelight.com/sample-code/utilities/LvpAuthUtil.cs.zip) to Win RT.

**Question**

The C# authentication code hyperlinked below is not Win RT compatible. It's giving errors, how do i authenticate and retrieve video?

Comment: Did you read the errors?

Comment: yes i did, but after seeing the answer below it was clear, what the issue was. My first jump into app dev. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the .NET Framework from Microsoft Download Center http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851)and install
2. Browse and Add References from folder **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**
   [image]

Comment: thank you, you saved me a couple hours of searching. :-)